# How to fix: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: partialViewName

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I'm stuck more than 48hours on this problem.
I made a new user dashboard interface and I'm trying to display "_UserList" but the program considers it NULL. I don't understand why. If I look in SSMS there are data in "_UserList".

I know how to overcome this error by checking if `@Html.Partial((string)ViewData["_UserList"])` is NULL. But this is not my problem. I don't understand why it is considered NULL.

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="dashboard-icons">
    @Html.Partial((string)ViewData["_UserList"])
</div>
```

_UserList.cshtml

```
@using LIB.BusinessObjects
@if (((Dictionary<long, User>)ViewData["List"]).Count > 0)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gLatestDashboardId = @(((Dictionary<long, LIB.BusinessObjects.User>)ViewData["List"]).Values.First(i => i.Id>0).Id);
        var gDashboardItemsCount = @(((Dictionary<long, LIB.BusinessObjects.User>)ViewData["List"]).Count);
    </script>
    <form class="table-widget">
        <div class="dashboard-ico">
            <div class="outer-ico">
                <div class="widget-caption">
                    @MedCore.Helpers.T.Str("Users", "DashBoard", "Utilizatori sistemului")
                </div>
                <div class="data-grid-container">
                    <div class="data-grid">
                        <div class="data-grid-title-row">
                            <div class="data-grid-title">N</div>
                            <div class="data-grid-title">Login</div>
                            <div class="data-grid-title">@MedCore.Helpers.T.Str("Name", "DashBoard", "Nume")</div>
                            <div class="data-grid-title">@MedCore.Helpers.T.Str("LastLogin", "DashBoard", "Ultimul login")</div>
                            <div class="data-grid-title">@MedCore.Helpers.T.Str("DateCreated", "DashBoard", "Creat la")</div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.Partial("Controls/_UsersRows")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear" style="height:1px"></div>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: Do you have any redirections happening before it gets to this page?  ViewData could be losing its information on redirect.  You can try switching to ViewBag to see if it fixes the issue

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not very clear. Who is filling ViewData? And how is "List" related to your question? Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Where is `ViewData["_UserList"]` and `ViewData["List"]` being filled out?
Are you trying to store the name of the partial template in `ViewData["_UserList"]`?

I'm guessing you want to render the partial "_UserList.cshtml", and the data you want to show is stored in `ViewData["List"]`. If that's the case, try to just say `@Html.Partial("_UserList")` in the Index template.